# Auto declare base class pure virtual functions in derived class using Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

Is there any way in Eclipse CDT to automatically declare all the (pure) virtual functions of base class in derived classes.  I think my question is similar to this post on Eclipse community forum: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/352408/

I thought it is quite an obvious need for rapid development but unfortunately cannot really find an answer for it.

Looking forward to your answers, Thanks!